# How to get an x-axis adapted to audio/acoustics with pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, audio, spectrum

When plotting frequency response curves:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
w, h = signal.freqz([1, -1])
x = w * 44100 * 1.0 / (2 * np.pi)
y = 20 * np.log10(abs(h))
```

then `plt.plot(x, y)` and `plt.semilogx(x, y)` give:

[image]
[image]

but none of them have the "standard x-axis used in audio".

**Question: how to have the x-axis usually used in audio applications?** It includes:

- some sort of logarithmic axis, but not sure: is it really a normal logarithmic axis (see examples after)?
- axis from 20 to 20Khz, and ticks `["20", "50", "100", "200", "500", "1K", "2K", "5K", "10K", "20K"]`

Here are a few examples of what I mean:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this to your liking?

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax.set(xscale="log")
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid(which="both", axis='both')
_ = plt.xticks([20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000,20000], 
               ["20", "50", "100", "200", "500", "1K", "2K", "5K", "10K", "20K"])
```

[image]